# Why Nginx response extremely slow while accessing my Rails app (Both running on same Windows machine)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, nginx

I have both a working `Rails 4` application (`http://localhost:3000`) and `Nginx` server (`http://localhost:80`) accessible through the browser.

`Nginx` has been configured as reverse proxy with my `Rails 4` app so that `http://localhost` actually reaches my rails application http://localhost:3000. Now, this is working fine but the web pages get displayed extremely slowly whenever I access the application through Nginx. I have configured `Tomcat` with `Apache Web Server` in past and never slowness problem before and practically speaking `Nginx` is said to much lighter and faster than `Apache Web Server`.

This makes me think if I have configured my Rails app with Nginx correctly?

**Modified nginx.conf**

```
    server {
            listen       80;
            server_name  localhost;

            #charset koi8-r;

            #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

            location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            }
         ...
     ...
}
```

Comment: Figured it out. It's because of some graph building that's happening my app on every click.

Comment: Could you answer your own question please? Just to take it off the list of unanswered questions. Thank you.